# Logging only for simple Location in apache2

Tags: apache2

I'd like to know if it is sowehow possible to log some single `Location` to a specific log file.

Consider the following pseudo config:

```
<VirtualHost xyc>
  ErrorLog xyc.log
  <Location /bar
    ErrorLog bar.log
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

According to {https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#errorlog] the ErrorLog is only valid in the `server config` and `virtual host` config.

Is it possible to log ErrorLog (or CustomLog)  for just this Location/Directory `/bar`? Any workaround?

I'm fine with either a duplicate copy of access/error log or a redirect of the access/error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional logging, see "Conditional Logs" in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Basically something like:

```
SetEnv dolog 0

<Location /bar>
SetEnv dolog 1
</Location>

CustomLog access_log common env=dolog
```

Comment: I had completely forgotten about conditional logging. Great suggestion and thanks for the example.